# How can I extract only the white pixels from a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I need to use some existing images with some white icon glyphs inside them and extract only the glyph part . Imagine the iPhone's Phone.app icon, which is green around, and has a white telephone icon in the middle. I would need to extract only the telephone icon, without the green background (and keep a transparency around it) .

I tried using CGDataProviderCopyData and iterate through the pixel values and change them, 
but I am not familiar with graphics techniques and I had no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The image formats are easy to "crack" with regular old code.  All the info you need is readily available on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a fixed amount of images that you want to extract the while glyphs from or is it going to be continuous?

If its a fixed amount then that's a job for photoshop and not a question for here. If its for a stream of continuous images then I would suggest looking at the pixel values again.

A white pixel is (255,255,255) if you want to include near white pixels in your search you could include any pixels above a certain threshold. For example any pixels with all three values above 230.

So.. (<230,<230,<230)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you.This answers my question. I managed to do this by limiting the pixel values. I'll play around with the range to perfect it.